# Is there a textile like material that can act as a spring?

Tags: material-science

Imagine some sort of textile (as in very light, not metallic) that is tightly rolled up, can be easily unrolled by applying some force (i.e pulling it) but when released will eventually return to it's rolled up state, over and over again.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding specific materials.

Comment: I couldn't find a more appropriate place on stackexchage to ask this question.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it is still off-topic in my view. Just because you think no one else will answer this, it doesn't mean we will. You question does definitely not fall within our scope as defined in the [help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to offend you. I thought material science was a topic on this site and that my question was appropriate for that, perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: Don't worry, you did not *offend* me (or anyone else, I hope). Material science is on-topic, if it is about concepts, like everything else. We do never deal in specific applications of science though, which this constitutes, IMO, since that is the domain of engineering.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're asking about some sort of [smart material](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_material), specifically a shape-memory polymer. Something, maybe, like [this from inventables](https://www.inventables.com/technologies/shape-memory-polymer--2), or [this from CRG](http://www.crgrp.com/rd-center/shape-memory-polymers). You could check out [this from NCSU](http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-08/watch-electric-field-turn-gel-tiny-claws)

Now, if you mean *textile* as in *cloth*, I'm afraid I could not easily find one. Of course, many of these gels/polymers could be put into cloth, and may yield the desired results. (Like what [these people did](http://www.fibre2fashion.com/industry-article/18/1738/development-of-shape-memory-fabrics-garments1.asp)!)

It should be noted that most of these things don't actually re-form of their own accord; most of them need some sort of temperature or electric current to do so.

There are a few materials that "bend" back due to internal stresses. Indeed, most materials exhibit that behavior. I doubt that's what you're looking for, as it is just the same type of bending that you do on everyday objects, and generally would not have that easy-to-manipulate quality.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer. This definitely points me in the right direction.